# parser error: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected ' }'

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets

````
contract agram {
  string public name;
  uint public imageCount = 0;
  mapping(uint => Image) public images;

  struct Image {
    uint id;
    string hash;
    string description;
    uint tipAmount;
    address payable author;
  }

  event ImageCreated(
    uint id,
    string hash,
    string description,
    uint tipAmount,
    address payable author
  );

  event ImageTipped(
    uint id,
    string hash,
    string description,
    uint tipAmount,
    address payable author
  );

  constructor() public {
    name = "agram";
  }

  function uploadImage(string memory _imgHash, string memory _description) public {
    // Make sure the image hash exists
    require(bytes(_imgHash).length > 0);
    // Make sure image description exists
    require(bytes(_description).length > 0);
    // Make sure uploader address exists
    require(msg.sender!=address(0));

    // Increment image id
    imageCount ++;

    // Add Image to the contract
    images[imageCount] = Image(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);
    // Trigger an event
    emit ImageCreated(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, msg.sender);
  }

  function tipImageOwner(uint _id) public payable {
    // Make sure the id is valid
    require(_id > 0 && _id <= imageCount);
    // Fetch the image
    Image memory _image = images[_id];
    // Fetch the author
    address payable _author = _image.author;
    // Pay the author by sending them Ether
    address(_author).transfer(msg.value);
    // Increment the tip amount
    _image.tipAmount = _image.tipAmount + msg.value;
    // Update the image
    images[_id] = _image;
    // Trigger an event
    emit ImageTipped(_id, _image.hash, _image.description, _image.tipAmount, _author);
  }```
````

Comment: Did you copy this code from somhwere? Coz it seems you are missing "}" at the end to close the contract. However, there are other issues after that. But you might be able to solve them, as they are more common.

Answer (score 1):

```
   contract agram {
      string public name;
      uint public imageCount = 0;
      mapping(uint => Image) public images;
    
      struct Image {
        uint id;
        string hash;
        string description;
        uint tipAmount;
        address payable author;
      }
    
      event ImageCreated(
        uint id,
        string hash,
        string description,
        uint tipAmount,
        address payable author
      );
    
      event ImageTipped(
        uint id,
        string hash,
        string description,
        uint tipAmount,
        address payable author
      );
    
      constructor() public {
        name = "agram";
      }
    
      function uploadImage(string memory _imgHash, string memory _description) public {
        // Make sure the image hash exists
        require(bytes(_imgHash).length > 0);
        // Make sure image description exists
        require(bytes(_description).length > 0);
        // Make sure uploader address exists
        require(msg.sender!=address(0));
    
        // Increment image id
        imageCount++;
    
        // Add Image to the contract
        images[imageCount] = Image(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0,payable(msg.sender));
        // Trigger an event
        emit ImageCreated(imageCount, _imgHash, _description, 0, payable (msg.sender));
      }
    
      function tipImageOwner(uint _id) public payable {
        // Make sure the id is valid
        require(_id > 0 && _id <= imageCount);
        // Fetch the image
        Image memory _image = images[_id];
        // Fetch the author
        address payable _author = _image.author;
        // Pay the author by sending them Ether
        _author.transfer(msg.value);
        // Increment the tip amount
        _image.tipAmount = _image.tipAmount + msg.value;
        // Update the image
        images[_id] = _image;
        // Trigger an event
        emit ImageTipped(_id, _image.hash, _image.description, _image.tipAmount, _author);
      }
    
    }
```

I edited the code so it compiles without error, only warnings. Hope this helps you edit further changes.